# Why `this` is not point to js global scope in the code example

Tags: javascript, this

Why `this` is not point to js global scope in the code below ?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var valueHolder = {
    value: '',
    setValue: function(newValue) {
        this.value = newValue;
    },
    getValue: function() {
        return this.value;
    }
}

valueHolder.setValue("hello world");

alert(valueHolder.getValue()); // return "hello world"
alert(valueHolder.value);      // return "hello world"
alert(window.value);           // return "undefined"

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the reference to the function (c.f. 11.2.3 of [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)):

```
var valueHolder = {
    value: '',
    setValue: function(newValue) {
        this.value = newValue;
    },
    getValue: function() {
        return this.value;
    }
}

var set = valueHolder.setValue,
    get = valueHolder.getValue;

set('test');

alert(get());                  // return "test"
alert(valueHolder.value);      // return ""
alert(window.value);           // return "test"
```

When referred to **in context** `this` is set to the relevant context (`valueHolder` in your example). In my example above, the function definitions are clearly identical, but the function references are not in the context of any object, and in that case `this` is set to the global context (`window`).

Answer (score 2):

it returns undefined because value is a key inside an object and is not visible inside the window object. you will access using

```
window.valueHolder.value
```

(to be clear, in your code `this` keyword is referring to valueHolder object)

Comment: -1 because question is "Why [this] is not point to js global scope in the code below" or in other words "Why [this] keyword is referring to valueHolder object"

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think it would be the global scope?

When an object has a property that references a function and you call that function using dot notation like this:

```
valueHolder.getValue();
```

Then within the function JavaScript automatically sets `this` to be the object.